# Facebook like button taking URL from og:url instead of provided URL

Tags: facebook-like

When hitting like on facebook like button it does not share the correct URL as provided but using the URL which is in the og:url. I am seeing the correct URL being posted in the browser iframe but when seeing the same in the facebook (link posted) then it ignore the parameter posted in the URL. See the following sample:

Actual URL posted: https://sub.domain.com/Welcome.aspx?s=a1111&lang=en&refid=fb1&sms=5

Facebook showing this as: https://sub.domain.com/Welcome.aspx?s=a1111

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Like button tends to ignore all parameters passed to the URL. You will need to use something like `mod_rewrite` to create `unique` URLs for each page the user can like. The way to achieve this is to mask the query variable as a page.

I've written a quick tutorial here:
http://www.webniraj.com/2011/09/06/using-htaccess-files-to-hide-query-variables/

But Google around and you will find more information on how to do it for your server / environment.

Comment: But facebook is taking the parameters as i showed in the above data sample. In the og:url i have one querystring parameter which is render on the facebook like link. Is this new implementation from facebook as the same thing working fine few days back and now it just consider the og:url?

Comment: Odd if it worked before. Try using the Lint took to scrape the page and see what errors / issues facebook reports: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug